# How to include strings in series data to pull for tooltip point formatting?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

beginner here, I'm trying to build a column graph that shows a username on the x axis, and a test score on the y axis.  In the tooltips box, I'm trying to make it so it shows the test score and the date the test was taken.  I'm using PHP to populate the graph based on an oracle sql database, so I'm mixing PHP into my javascript for Highcharts.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is actually possible, but I'm trying to take the test date from the sql database, and plug it into the series data, so I can call it out into the tooltips box (that way when you hover over the column, it'll tell you the user, the score, and the date they took the exam).

This is what I'm trying, and it isn't working, because I'm guessing series data has something against strings instead of numeric.  Any help you can offer would be awesome!  Thanks!

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="graph1" style="height: 400px; width: <?php echo $chartspace ?>px"></div>
<input id="width" type="range" value="<?php echo $chartspace ?>" min="300" max="<?php echo $chartspacemax ?>" />

<script>
$(function () { 
    $('#graph1').highcharts({
  credits: { enabled:false},
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Most Recent Test Scores'
        },
  subtitle: {
            text: 'Drag slider to change the chart width'
        },
        xAxis: {
    categories: [
    
    <?php
    
   $i = 0;
  do {
  echo "'";
  echo $userinfos[$i]['username'];
  echo "',";
  $i++;
   } while ($i<=$count); ?>
                ]
        },
        yAxis: { 
   plotLines: [{
    color: 'red',
    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
    value: 85,
    width: 1,
   }],  
      floor: 0,
            ceiling: 100,
            title: {
                text: 'Test Score (%)'
            }
        },
        series: [{
   showInLegend: false,
   name: 'Test Score',
            data: [
   
        <?php
     
    $i = 0;
   do {
   if($userinfos[$i]['score'] >= 85){
   echo "{y:";
   echo $userinfos[$i]['score'];
   echo ", testdate:";
   echo $userinfos[$i]['most_recent_test_date'];
   echo ", color: '#00A6CF'},";}
   else{
   echo "{y:";
   echo $userinfos[$i]['score'];
   echo ", testdate:";
   echo $userinfos[$i]['most_recent_test_date'];
   echo ", color: 'red'},";}
   $i++;
   } while ($i<=$count-1); ?>]
   }],
  tooltip: {
   shared: true,
   useHTML: true,
   pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">Score: </td>' +
                '<td style="text-align: right">{point.y} %</td></tr><tr><br><td>Date: </td>' +
                '<td style="text-align: right">{point.testdate}</td></tr>'
  }
    });
$('#width').bind('input', function () {
        $('#graph1').highcharts().setSize(this.value, 400, false);
    });
 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do should definitely be possible.  Here's an example of that working:

http://jsfiddle.net/thfbx7gb/

However, in this case I pulled out the PHP and replaced it with some hard-coded data.

```
   data: [{y:7, color: '#00A6CF', testdate: '2014-12-12'},{y:2, color:"#FF0000", testdate: '2015-01-03'}, {y:3,color:"#00FF00", testdate:'2014-10-19'}]
```

So I think the problem is that you're mixing in PHP with javascript and getting some strange results.  It's generally a very bad idea to include inline PHP into javascript code like you're doing if for no other reason that it's really, really hard to read and debug.

A few things jump out at me:

You shouldn't be using PHP for this at all, but if you must then you shouldn't be using do-while loops like you are.  You're using a do/while with an incrementor instead of a for loop:

```
$i = 0;
    do {
        echo "'";
        echo $userinfos[$i]['username'];
        echo "',";
        $i++;
    } while ($i<=$count);
```

This should really be:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) {
  echo "'{$userinfos[$i]['username']}'";
}
```

You should be able to see how the other do/while loops you're using could be reduced to a much more succinct for loop.

But that still doesn't eliminate the whole problem of including PHP code in your javascript.  You should really be either hard coding this data or loading it from an external source of some kind.  The typical way of doing that would be with an AJAX call to load the data and then pass that in to the chart directly.

You would have a file that generates the data object directly and outputs that as as JSON string using json_ecode();

```
$output = array();

foreach ($userinfos as $user) {
  $output['categories'][] = $user['username'];
  if ($user['score'] >= 85) {
    $color = "#00A6CF";
  } else {
    $color = "#FF0000";
  }
  $user['color'] = $color;
  $output['seriesdata'][] = $user;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

This should give you a JSON object which you can read work with pretty easily.  Something along the lines of this (which is untested, it may not work without a bit of fiddling):

```
$.getJSON('/generate.php', function(data) {

   $('#graph1').highcharts({
        credits: { enabled:false},
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Most Recent Test Scores'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Drag slider to change the chart width'
        },
        xAxis: {
             categories: data.categories
        yAxis: {    
            plotLines: [{
                color: 'red',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                value: 85,
                width: 1,
            }],     
            floor: 0,
            ceiling: 100,
            title: {
                text: 'Test Score (%)'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
            name: 'Test Score',
            data: data.seriesdata,
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">Score: </td>' +
                '<td style="text-align: right">{point.y} %</td></tr><tr><br><td>Date: </td>' +
                '<td style="text-align: right">{point.testdate}</td></tr>'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem was not surrounding the string with quotes!